# When to use lim-notation and when to use f(x)->L, x->a notation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, notation

I was wondering if there is an important distinction between the following two notations for limits:

$a_n\to L$ when $n\to\infty$

and

$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$

From what I could find it seems like quibbling. I'm currently working with limits of sequences so it's mostly in regard to limits of sequences that I'm asking, however, I am wondering the same thing about limits of function.

Comment: Replace for by when.

Comment: Both are correct in any context.

Comment: They mean the same thing. In general, the first way is a stylistic thing when you don't want that to seem like a major calculation. Usually, the second way is more formal and used as a punch line for a harder calculation. This is more obvious, perhaps, in research papers.

Comment: Actually, you could write the first as:   "As $n\to \infty$, $a_n \to L$," which is a closer approximation to the more formal, universally understood $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = L$.

Comment: @amWhy: I'm going to disagree with you on that habit. Saying "As $n\to \infty,\, a_n \to L$" does not read like the if-then that it should. It can be interpreted as saying $n\to \infty$ and $a_n \to L$ are both hypotheses. You always want words (if necessary) to distinguish supposition and conclusion.

Comment: Fine, my point was, @zugzug, that I prefer "if $n\to \infty,$ then $a_n\to L$".  Since you aren't familiar with various translations of an implication, I'm surprised you didn't object to $q,$ when $p$, and did not insist the OP write IF $p$, THEN $q$.  "when" isn't very good at distinguishing supposition and conclusions. But you seemed to assume it does, just as I know that as x approaches infinity, the function then approaches L.

Comment: @amWHy: I did not mean to insult you; you are probably a much better mathematician than me. I was mostly thinking about the OP's level while they are habit building. You are absolutely right that "q when p" is strange. It's always bothered me. That's why when I do $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs, I usually say "when x... it follows that ______".

Comment: No problem, @zugzug. No offense taken. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are identical. When you write $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n)$, context should be enough to figure out whether $n$ is an integer or a real number. Personally however, I use the arrows for sequences, and the $\lim$ for functions.